# How to drop multiple columns from a pandas dataframe if it contains any alphabet (non numeric)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pulled data from hive into python using pyhive. Now I have created a dataframe from the data imported. The dtype of all the columns in the dataframe is object. I wanted to know the best way to drop any column in the data frame that contains an alphabet(non numeric)?

df.select_dtypes(['number']) wouldnt work since all my columns are dtype=object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will convert numeric strings to number dtypes and select only the numeric dtypes from the DataFrame.

```
#convert number columns to numeric
df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
df=df.select_dtypes('number')
```